# problems with ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker

Tags: angular, eonasdan-datetimepicker

i have a problems with ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker i installed via npm , i put the row in angular-cli

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "../node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper-utils.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "../node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"
```

i put aswell this import in app.module

```
import {A2Edatetimepicker} from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker';

    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
      A2Edatetimepicker
  ]
```

this is my template

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control"
           a2e-datetimepicker
           [date]="date"
           [options]="a2eOptions"
           (onChange)="dateChange($event)"
           (onClick)="dateClick()"
    />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

i based myself on this example of eonasdan-datetimepicker

https://embed.plnkr.co/vnU3TedIRqOFGXWRbXt0/

and i have this error in console

```
this.dpElement.datetimepicker is not a function
```

i don't know how handle it so i need your help

thanks in advance

Comment: does anyone know ?

Comment: this is now solved, use the latest version.

Comment: what version eliminates this issue???